# Correct use of before and after

Tags: sentence-construction

Context

Our boss messaged us not to come to the office today. But before that message we were already reached to the office.

How would I say this in one sentence?

A) He messaged us after we reached to the office.

B) He messaged us before that we reached to the office.

Comment: "were already reached" is not grammatical.  It should be *"**had** already reached"*, or *"**were** already **at**"*

Answer (score 1):

You use "before" correctly in your sentence - "your arrival" was **before** "the message".

Therefore the opposite is true, "the message" was **after** "your arrival":

> A) He messaged us **after** we reached <strike>to</strike> the office.

note: the "to" was incorrectly used here.

Also:

> We reached the office **before** he messaged us.

Comment: *We reached **to** the office* does not reflect the intended meaning. The *to* should be removed.